# Custom UILabel Text Alignment

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

After research i have found that, there are only three Default options for label text alignment are **aligned left, right and center**.

Beside this if i don't want any of these alignment and want my own custom alignment of the text accord to my desire.can i achieve this? If there are any suggestions please provide.

Why i want this is
i have label and align the text to left. But i need certain boundary in the label and i provided it. But when i provide the boundary to the label then the first letter of the cannot be seen properly because of the boundary width.I need to align the word from left neither right nor center.

What can i do in this case.???

Comment: What is the desired text alignment?

Comment: neither totally left neither from center..

Comment: Can you provide an example? What are you trying to achieve overall?

Comment: ok i will describe further

Comment: I don't tested yet! Add an empty space to your label

Comment: Yeah! It's should work

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do exactly. Having some screenshot samples could help. For UITextView, there is exclusion paths, else, you could use NSParagraphStyle to add some specific head/tail indents.

Comment: @Sam Did you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSAttributedString` with a `NSParagraphStyle` to set indent values.  You can indent the first line, or all lines with these parameters:

- `firstLineHeadIndent`
- `headIndent`
- `tailIndent`

**Alternatively**

For single line labels that need some padding, I often use a `UIButton` with `isUserInteractionEnabled=false`. Then you can easily set `contentInsets` without worrying about setting an `NSAttributedString` and you get vertical padding as well.